# Execute command in all immediate subdirectories

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I'm trying to add a shell function (zsh) `mexec` to execute the same command in all immediate subdirectories e.g. with the following structure

```
~
-- folder1
-- folder2
```

`mexec pwd` would show for example

```
/home/me/folder1
/home/me/folder2
```

I'm using `find` to pull the immediate subdirectories. The problem is getting the passed in command to execute. Here's my first function defintion:

```
mexec() {
    find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | xargs -I'{}' \
    /bin/zsh -c "cd {} && $@;";
}
```

only executes the command itself but doesn't pass in the arguments i.e. `mexec ls -al` behaves exactly like `ls`

Changing the second line to `/bin/zsh -c "(cd {} && $@);"`, `mexec` works for just `mexec ls` but shows this error for `mexec ls -al`:

```
zsh:1: parse error near `ls'
```

Going the exec route with find

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec /bin/zsh -c "(cd {} && $@)" \;
```

Gives me the same thing which leads me to believe there's a problem with how I'm passing the arguments to zsh. This also seems to be a problem if I use bash: the error shown is:

```
-a);: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

What would be a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Can you try using this simple loop which loops in all sub-directories at one level deep and execute commands on it,

```
for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && ls -al); done
```

`(cmd1 && cmd2)` opens a sub-shell to run the commands. Since it is a child shell, the parent shell (the shell from which you're running this command) retains its current folder and other environment variables.

Wrap it around in a function in a proper `zsh` script as

```
#!/bin/zsh

function runCommand() {
    for d in ./*/ ; do /bin/zsh -c "(cd "$d" && "$@")"; done
}

runCommand "ls -al"
```

should work just fine for you.

Comment: `ls -al` in this case is just an example command I'm running in every sub-directory. I'd want it to be free-form, regardless of what command I use.

I'll try the for loop.

Comment: @Zahymaka: I have added a more generic way of doing this, by adding a function. Don't forget to accept/upvote it once you find it solving your problem.

Comment: This function doesn't work if there's a quote in the directory name (zsh:1: unmatched ')

Comment: Nice. Seeing your quotes prompted me to try running my original `mexec` with quotes. What do you know, it worked!

Comment: Good. If anyone needs to execute commands in all sub-directories at two levels deep, you can simply use `./*/*/`

Answer (score 6):

```
#!/bin/zsh
# A simple script with a function...

mexec()
{ 
  export THE_COMMAND=$@
  find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} zsh -c 'cd "{}" && echo "{}" && echo "$('$THE_COMMAND')" && echo -e'
}

mexec ls -al
```

Comment: This one should work even with directories with quotes and other strange characters

Comment: The two echos are a hack. Not sure why -e wouldn't work on the first one.

Comment: I just realized my original works if I call `mexec 'ls -al'` with the command in quotes. So does this. Thanks!

Comment: Just remember your method still won't work with directories containing many directory legal characters. Your script will give an error "xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option" or similar depending on the characters used.

Comment: Got it. Very unlikely I'll have directories with quotes in them.

Answer (score 3):

using https://github.com/sharkdp/fd but you could as well use plain old find instead of fdfind

```sh
function inDirs() { fdfind --type d --max-depth 1 --exec bash -c "x={} && echo && echo \$x && echo \${x//?/=} && cd {} && echo '-> '$* && $*" ; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a parallelized version of this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Command to run in each directory
COMMAND="ls -l"

# Export the command so it is available to xargs
export COMMAND

# Function to run the specified command in a directory
run_command() {
    dir="$1"
    eval "$COMMAND $dir" # this runs the command on $dir, like 'go build ./mydir'
}

export -f run_command

# Find all directories and run the command in parallel
# -type d finds directories
# -maxdepth 1 ensures only the immediate subdirectories are found
# -mindepth 1 excludes the current directory (.)
# -print0 and -0 handle directories with spaces in their names
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 4 -I {} bash -c 'run_command "$@"' _ {}

# Note: Adjust the -P flag to change the number of parallel processes
```